# Is there a way to lock Firefox proxy settings so they cannot be circumvented?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, proxy, privoxy

I set up privoxy to enforce a whitelist system for my own PC (Ubuntu 20.04 + Regolith 2.0 / i3wm) to fight a serious internet addiction / OCD issue that has been haunting me for years.

Privoxy and the whitelist are working just fine.

However, I know from experience that I will eventually just circumvent this by changing proxy settings in Firefox.

My plan is to create an `autoconfig` file and `lock` proxy settings. Should this file be root-access only, the final step would be easy - I would just hand over the root access to my wife and downgrade to a regular user.

My proxy settings are as follows:

[image: screenshot of the proxy settings]

I have properly created an `autoconfig.js` and a `firefox.cfg` files, which were moved to

```
/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref
```

The `firefox.cfg` file is:

```
// IMPORTANT: Start your code on the 2nd line
lockPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
lockPref("network.proxy.http", "proxy.proxy.com")
lockPref("network.proxy.http_port", 8118)
lockPref("network.proxy.https_port", 8118)
lockPref("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", true)
lockPref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "127.0.0.1,localhost")
```

**I can still edit proxy settings freely, though**

**I have a few questions troubleshooting this:**

1. Should the autoconfig files be elsewhere?
2. Are the parameters in `firefox.cfg` correct? I suspect there are several inconsistencies here, but found no sane defaults for newbies.

**EDIT**
I eventually found a way to circumvent this too by loging in in ubuntu recovery mode as root, then granting myself sudo privileges again from the terminal. The ultimate solution involves password-protecting the root user.

Comment: Have you followed *exactly* the guide-lines as described in the article
[Customizing Firefox Using AutoConfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig)?

Comment: Thank you, @harrymc. Yes I did. Up to a certain point. The contents of  the `firefox.cfg` were taken from a different source.

Comment: Please post also your autoconfig.js file (delete sensitive data). Note: The article specifies the `defaults/pref` directory, while you say `defaults` only.

Comment: Thank you, Harry. I had overlooked a part of the article. I had the `.cfg` file in `/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref` whereas the articles indicated it should be "at the top level of the Firefox directory". I eventually understood this means `/usr/lib/firefox/`. After correcting this, everything is fine and the gui menus for these items are now grayed out.

Comment: I will delete the question once you get the thank you note, as I suspect this should be classified as "Not reproducible/caused by a typo" kind of question

Comment: @GuedesBF better keep it as future reference for others with the same goal. Note that for deleting too many questions your account could get suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to configure the proxy is using Firefox Enterprise Policies. The [proxy settings](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#proxy) are described in their README file.
The [Enterprise Policy Generator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enterprise-policy-generator/) Firefox addon is an easy way to create the policies file.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, it looks much easier than my original method